# how can I deploy my mern website from my local machine?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-applications, web-deployment

I have a fully functioning MERN app working. I was wondering, how would I deploy my mern app to the world wide web from my local machine?

My research has concluded with XAMPP as a possible tool, but it seems the backend tooling is PHP not nodejs. Any ideas you guys have helps!

the idea is to host it locally not externally on the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to buy vps server. After you need to upload full project to the server through ftp software and need to upload packages with npm install/update. After these are finished download nginx server to the server and be carefull about port of project. If your project will running for example on 3000 port you may change nginx configuration like this and restart nginx with followed command:

**systemctl restart nginx**

and nginx configuration write like this (added example domain):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name yourdomain.com;

    root /var/projects/your_project_name;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
 
}
```

For additional information about nginx configurations you may visit [Nginx configurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/)

Comment: for sure! btw with this approach, i wont be running the project on someone else's server? will i? the goal is to run it on my machine and host it locally? - hopefully i am making sense. But thank you for your input.

Comment: you think correctly.. Xampp or other tools using like local environment. It will not help to you in server. You need know about linux and vps server's working mechanism . For config quickly you can use docker containers. Hovewer , in the end you need config nginx also.